# Organizing images in a grid like fashion

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to organize the images on this web page as two images side by side going down the page with an equal gap to the sides and on top. The format should look like:   (image) (image)
             and so forth going down the page.
I can't get the images with their descriptions to sit on the right side of the page as they all keep travelling downward. I originally thought that having a leftimg and a rightimg class would work but I couldn't seem to get that to work either.

```
<div class="maintext">
            <div class="leftimg">
                <img src="dinner1.jpg" width="400" height="300">
                <h3><span>Big American Burger</span></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="leftimg">
                <img src="dinner2.jpg" width="400" height="300">
                <h3><span>Tasty Carvery</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="leftimg">
                 <img src="dinner3.jpg" width="400" height="300">
                <h3><span>Sausage and Chips</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="leftimg">
                 <img src="dinner4.jpg" width="400" height="300">
                <h3><span>Delicious Deserts</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="leftimg">
                <img src="dinner5.jpg" width="400" height="300">
                <h3><span>Big American Burger</span></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="leftimg">
                <img src="dinner6.jpg" width="400" height="300">
                <h3><span>Tasty Carvery</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="leftimg">
                 <img src="dinner7.jpg" width="400" height="300">
                <h3><span>Sausage and Chips</span></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="leftimg">
                 <img src="dinner8.jpg" width="400" height="300">
                <h3><span>Delicious Deserts</span></h3>
            </div>
    </div>
```

And the css

```
.leftimg {
    position:relative; 
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    left:10%;

}

h3 span{ 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 65%; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    color: white; 
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
    letter-spacing: -1px;  
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i wouldn't use a fixed with considering that the screen size might be smaller.

but nevertheless you should use `float: left` or `display: inline-block` on the images.

and skip the `left: 10%` and use a `margin-left: 10%` instead

```
.leftimg {
    position:relative; 
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
```

if you want this whole thing centered on your page wrap it with following container and use `display: inline-block` on the images:

```
.parent-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.leftimg {
    position:relative; 
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

maybe i can help you with this fiddle!
You need to add `img {width: 100%}` in order to let the image be the size of its parent

Update 2:

it's really difficult for me to find out what you really need :) maybe you can provide further information (maybe a screenshot) what the expected outcome should be.

i added a `clear: both` every second image - maybe like this?

```
.leftimg:nth-child(2n - 1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

and instead of using `float: left` it's `float:right` now - so it's on the right side of the screen.. furthermore it's a little bit smaller `width: 25%`

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7a1ku48b/1/)

Comment: this works but now my images have jumped out of my maintext container?

Comment: yes, because you use a fixed height on the `.leftimg` container. just set it to `height: auto`

Comment: Apologies for my naivety, im still only getting the grasps of html. If i remove the fixed heights in my html code then the image jumps back up to its normal size? if i change it in my css it does nothing

Comment: edited and included a fiddle - it's easier that way :)

Comment: It is still not contained in the maintext container. it only jumps out when i include float:left

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122437/discussion-between-dylan-and-doml-the-bread).